# Azure Iot solution in VS2019 working only for first run after system restart

Tags: c#, docker, iot, azure-iot-edge

Im using windows 10 Pro running vs2019. I have tried the default [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-visual-studio-develop-module) in the docs. Im using azure container registry. I have noticed that the solution runs properly only for first time i restart my system. If i run my solution for the second time Im getting the issue "**IOException: Channel is closed**" , If i restart my system and run the solution again it will work and if i stop debug and run the solution again getting channel closed exception.

**Solution first run after system restart**
[image]

**Running solution for the second time**
[image]

Comment: I have reviewed the document and unable to repro the issue on my Win10 Pro. System(including system restart as well). Please re-check docker-running, IoT Edge Tools simulator is setup, no network/proxy issues, no updates pending on VS 2019 or OS. This might be an intermittent issue, please try again following the document, and leave a comment if you still face any issues.

Comment: i don't know the reason but , there were some updates in vs2019 which i have installed and restarted my system. from then on its working..

Comment: Could you please mark the below response as helpful by marking it as answer, this would be very helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed the document and unable to repro the issue on my Win10 Pro. System(including system restart as well).

**Please re-check** docker-running, IoT Edge Tools simulator is setup, no network/proxy issues, **no updates pending on VS 2019 or OS**.

This might be an intermittent issue on your device side,So please try again following the document, and leave a comment if you still face any issues.